# Keep strings of a specified length, in R

Tags: r, string, directory

I can use

```
dirs <- list.dirs("C:/Data", full.names = T, recursive = T) %>% 
strtrim(20) %>% 
unique()
```

to get strings of 20 characters or less, but how do I get excatly those strings having only 20 characters?

Comment: try `filter(nchar(dirs) == 20)`

Comment: @missuse: I get Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical" but it is listed as chr. i don't get this.

Comment: `library(tidyverse)
as.tibble(dirs) %>%
 filter(nchar(dirs) == 20)` or just `dirs[nchar(dirs) == 20]` `dirs` is a charcater but `nchar(dirs) == 20` is a logical vector.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `str_detect` with a regular expression to do this. Here the expression `^.{5}$` says match only strings that consist of the start, then 5 of any character, then the end of the string (5 because the example words dataset doesn't have 20-character words in it).

```r
library(stringr)
head(words)
#> [1] "a"        "able"     "about"    "absolute" "accept"   "account"
head(words[str_detect(words, "^.{5}$")])
#> [1] "about" "admit" "after" "again" "agent" "agree"
```

Created on 2018-02-26 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).